# Changing error code with javascript

Tags: javascript

Either my javascript or my template is broken.

This is my javascript to change error messages. I cannot change my template, because it is not accessible.

```
<!-- CHANGE ERROR MESSAGE -->
<script language="JavaScript">

  $(function() { 
    $.ajaxSetup({complete: function() { 
      $(".errorExplanation ul li:contains('Password and email do not match')").ReplaceWith('Password does not match');}}) 
  });

</script>
```

This is the part of the website that refuses to be translated:

[The code of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHsRU.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .replaceWith the r should be lowercase.

Comment: Does not work. I don't think lowercase or uppercase has anything to do with it. I think the error code 'password and e-mail..' are part of another section that I do not understand (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider just using a more generalized selector such as `span.error-message:contains('...')` and just using jQuery's [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to set the content :

```
$("span.error-message:contains('Password and email do not match')").text('Password does not match');
```

If you need it to be more specific, you could use an identifier like `#pattern` from your example code :

```
$("#pattern span.error-message:contains('Password and email do not match')").text('Password does not match');
```

You can see a very basic example demonstrated below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <pre>Original</pre>
  <span class='original-error-message'>
        Password and email do not match
  </span>
  <pre>Replaced</pre>
  <span class='error-message'>
        Password and email do not match
  </span>
  
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(function() { 
      // Replace any spans with class 'error-message' that contain
      // your specific text
      $("span.error-message:contains('Password and email do not match')").text('Password does not match');
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it is not working. It might be the .html part, but i really think it is some section.

Comment: I've updated it to use `text()`, which is more appropriate since you are just using plain text and added an example, which works.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much! Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.text()` method to replace the text, make it simpler:

```
$(function(){
    $("span.error-message").text('Password does not match');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$('.error-message span').html('Password does not match');
```